# Increase the time for Magento Cache

Tags: cache

i am using Magento website with around 200 Website and each website having three storeview. But products data only available in Main website with  3 store views. the problem i am facing now soon some on refresh the cache server completely hangs. so i am trying to know from where i can increase cache time so it not expires or from where i can disable auto refresh cache option please help me

Comment: For a store of that size, you can probably disable the Magento cache completely and rely on server caching

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons the server hangs as soon as you invalidate the cache can be a **high number of concurrent visitors** on your server.

As soon as you invalidate the cache, concurrent requests cause the cache generation process to start over until it is finished.
This will likely hang out your server.

I warmly suggest you to take a look at **Paul Partington**'s [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wC3IEt7gfqY&feature=youtu.be) and [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/paupartington/mage-titans-2015) taken from a talk of his.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Cache lifetime depends on the block type you're using. Each module can have it's own configured cache lifetime. How about refreshing your cache at night using a `crontab`? And after this use a `cache warmer`. So your visitors won't notice the site being slow.

Side question: You have over 600 storeviews? Why?